# When importing CSV to SQL in SSIS, I am losing my regional letters (Polish)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

1. I import a csv to SQL server in SSIS. Here's what my settings look like:

[image: Screenshot]

2. The system firstly suggests 6501 and then in preview all letters look properly. However, when I proceed, it throws an error saying that it cannot proceed as it's really a 1252.
3. I change to 1252 and it all works now. However, I suddenly loose my regional letters. Here's what it looks like

[image: Screenshot2]

Here's what I've tried:

1. Changing to 1250, 65001 etc
2. Ticking Unicode
3. changing Locale to Polish, polish(Poland), English
4. googling
5. searching stack

I'd appreciate if someone could point me toward a direction as nothing comes to my mind.

Comment: What's the actual code page of the source file? It only makes sense to use 65001 when the file is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Open the `csv` file in something like Notepad++. In the status bar, it will show you the actual encoding, line endings and byte order mark (BOM). This can be the starting point.

Comment: I have opened the file in Notepad++ and the status bar says it's UTF-8.

Comment: If it doesn't actually say `UTF-8-BOM` in the status bar then Notepad++ is only guessing the encoding. Try selecting `Encoding > Encode in UTF-8-BOM`, save the file, then close and reopen it to confirm the change. After saving it with a BOM (Byte Order Mark) try importing it via SSIS again using code page `65001 (UTF-8)` setting and see if it works.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - thanks for the advice. I've just tried it and unfortunately it didn't work. For some reason it just throws the old error for each column:

`Error at Data Flow Task [SQL Server Destination [9]]: The column "ColumnName" cannot be processed because more than one code page (65001 and 1252) are specified for it.`

It's very strange as I chose 'convert to utf8 bom' as you've suggested and saved it.