# Failing to convert a CSV file to UTF-8 BOM(w/ Notepad++) in order to migrate it to SQL w/ SSIS and keep regional(Polish) letters

Tags: sql-server, csv, utf-8, ssis, notepad++

1. I have a CSV in Polish that  I want to get into SQL w/ SSIS.
2. I open it in Notepad++ and it says UTF 8.
3. 

> `If it doesn't actually say UTF-8-BOM in the status bar then Notepad++ is only guessing the encoding. Try selecting Encoding > Encode in UTF-8-BOM, save the file, then close and reopen it to confirm the change. After saving it with a BOM (Byte Order Mark) try importing it via SSIS again using code page 65001 (UTF-8) setting and see if it works`.

@AlwaysLearning

I convert the file as the user above suggested and it now shows UTF8 BOM in the corner. I save it.

4. So here's the vicious circle:

**a)** when choosing the CSV in SSIS as UTF-8 in the preview I can see my polish letters properly. Until I hit Run. Then I get this error:
`Error at Data Flow Task [SQL Server Destination [9]]: The column "ColumnName" cannot be processed because more than one code page (65001 and 1252) are specified for it.`
I get it for each column.

**b)** When I change the filetype in the connection manager to 1252, I can immediately see in the preview that my Polish letters are lost. But now running it works like a charm and I get no errors.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrLR4.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASovb.png)

**Here's what I've tried:**

1. Changing to 1250, 65001 etc
2. Ticking Unicode
3. changing Locale to Polish, polish(Poland), English
4. googling
5. searching stack
6. Posting [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68454296/when-importing-csv-to-sql-in-ssis-i-am-losing-my-regional-letters-polish?noredirect=1#comment120998003_68454296) question to stack:

Comment: The question make no sense. This is a UTF8 page. That's why I can write `Αυτό Εδώ` knowing it will appear correctly. 65001 is UTF8. What does `a CSV in Polish` mean? A file using the Windows-1250 encoding? You can import any file easily with SSIS just by specifying the *correct* encoding in the Flat File Source. No conversion is needed. If you use the SSMS wizard to import a non-Unicode (UTF16) file into `nvarchar` fields you'll see that a `Convert` transformation is added, that converts each field to Unicode

Comment: The wizard in SSDT is essentially the same as the SSMS Import Data Wizard and will also add a Convert transform if the file isn't UTF16

Comment: As for guessing, *all* single-byte codepages use the same bytes in the range 0-127. So does UTF8. Without a BOM, the only way to say that a file was created using one codepage or another is to find a byte that's invalid in other codepages. If the entire file contains bytes in the range 0-127 the codepage *doesn't* matter, as all would treat it the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did my best to understand your advice, yet I failed. Is there any chance you could explain to me in plain English what I can change in my actions to keep the regional letters?
Which is the CORRECT encoding that in your opinion I should choose? Because notepad++ says it's UTF8 and I've tried to choose everything - ended up in point 4, either a or b.